Will I have to accept (or reject) cookies every single time I visit StackExchange forever?
I'm not sure why if I am logged in, the stackexchange websites will not remember what my cookies preference is and never ask me again.
I am at this point of exhaustion with digital technology, that I often just close a tab and never go back to a website if a modal or a paywall ruin my experience of it, and the only reason I come back to stackexchange is that I have been using it for years, but I feel like the intrusiveness, redundancy and poor execution of the cookies modal dialog is wildly unnecessary. I probably clicked it over two hundred times in my life and I click whatever option will make it go away, knowing full well my choice doesn't make a difference at all and that I will be asked it again.
Is there an option to disable it somewhere in my settings, and I just haven't found it? Is my browser not remembering the choice my fault as a user?
What am I missing?
I use and own 4 devices that all have several browsers installed on them:
MacBook Pro with Safari, Firefox, Brave; iMac with Safari and Brave, MacBook Air with Safari and Brave, iPhone with Safari.
I see the modal each time and it makes my experience of the website miserable. It makes no sense that the setting would be saved on my end rather than as a user preference on Stack's servers.

Normal operation is that you make that cookie selection once, only. If you're needing to make the selection multiple times, then it's likely that your browser is either not saving or deleting your cookie settings. It's not uncommon for your browser to be set such that all locally stored information is deleted upon closing the browser. Another possibility is that you're limiting third-party cookies (or at least I thought they used third-party cookies for this) and/or JavaScript. It's difficult/impossible for us to accurately diagnose the issue based on the limited information you've provided.

This is indeed something on your end. The request saving the cookie selection is blocked on your end, which means the cookie dialog never goes away. If you use uBlock Origin, enable the annoyance and cookie filter lists. I am not sure which introduces the rule, but one of the extra built-in but default-disabled uBlock rules kills the cookie dialog in its entirety

I checked - you specifically want AdGuard - Cookie Notices

Problem is, SE does not handle it themselves. It's being done by third party service. Try to whitelist cookielaw.org domain in your browsers, and it should be able to save your preference and not show the dialog every time. (See here.)

Since we don't see others with this problem, it means this is something on your side. Perhaps all your browsers are set to maximum security, and delete all cookies and cache when you close the browser. Perhaps it's some security software you installed, doing the same. We can't know, but if you know or find the source of the block, you can likely fix it, for SE, by white listing the domain used to store the preferences.

You can also directly block the dialog in uBlock Origin by adding the following filter: stackexchange.com###onetrust-consent-sdk

@ShadowWizard you not seeing people actually taking the time to complain about the issue they are having absolutely doesn't mean that there are not thousands of people who are exasperated by this, that would be a convenient shortcut to think so without actual data. People have unfortunately built a strong resilience to the various annoyances of digital tech over the years. All my browsers are used mostly with their out-of-the-box settings (Safari, Brave, Firefox...) therefore I assume things are identical to almost every user unless they tweaked settings heavily or installed third-party apps
